# Disabling copy operation in QLPreviewController

Tags: first-responder, qlpreviewcontroller

Is there any way to disable copy of content when we are viewing a text file, in QLPreviewController?

I tried to sub-class it and override- canBecomeFirstResponder and returned NO, but it did not work :-(

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with viewDidAppear you can simply set:

```
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:nil];
```

And it will just remove the button for exporting from the previewer for you